# Initialize the code (in a actionscript file) in a different frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

How can I initialize this game in a differente frame with the function init? I'm working in Actionscript 3.0.

Hope you can help me.
 Heres the code (the code is in a actionscript file) :

```
package{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event; //used for ENTER_FRAME event

public class Main extends MovieClip{

    //constants
    const gravity:Number = 1.5;            //gravity of the game
    const dist_btw_obstacles:Number = 300; //distance between two obstacles
    const ob_speed:Number = 8;             //speed of the obstacle
    const jump_force:Number = 15;          //force with which it jumps

    //variables
    var player:Player = new Player();      
    var lastob:Obstacle = new Obstacle();  //varible to store the last obstacle in the obstacle array
    var obstacles:Array = new Array();     //an array to store all the obstacles
    var yspeed:Number = 0;                 //A variable representing the vertical speed of the bird
    var score:Number = 0;                  //A variable representing the score

    public function Main(){
        init();
    }

    function init():void {
        //initialize all the variables
        player = new Player();
        lastob = new Obstacle();
        obstacles = new Array();
        yspeed = 0;
        score = 0;

        //add player to center of the stage the stage
        player.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
        player.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
        addChild(player);
```

Comment: Do not call **init()** in the class constructor, call **init()** in that frame you want. It is **THAT** simple. Just keep in mind that mixing class scripting and multiframe timeline is a bad idea and is calling for various problems.

Comment: A friend was also telling me that and it works :D !! Thank you very much for answering me back <3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there are frame (for Adobe Animate projects), use `addFrameScript`:

```as
someMC.addFrameScript(2, myFunction);

private function myFunction():void{
  this.stop();
}
```

`myFunction` work if frame `2` would have existed.

If not, you can use Tween frameworks like [TweenLite or TweenMax](https://greensock.com/gsap-as) (Recommended):

```as
TweenLite.to(mc, 1.5, {onComplete:myFunction});
function myFunction():void {
    trace("tween finished");
}
```

`myFunction` is run after 1.5 sec

Comment: you don't need to use a heavy library like TweenLite for a simple timeout. This functionality is built in:    `flash.utils.setTimeout(myFunction, 1500);`

Comment: Also, addFrameScript is 0 based, so your `myFunction` would actually be on frame 3

Comment: Sounds good but the way Organis said is easier. Anyway thank you for answering me back, i thought this was an abondoned web page :p .